# Constructor is not defined for a mock class with jest

Tags: unit-testing, jestjs

I am currently trying to have a mock of a constructor. As written [in the documentation](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/es6-class-mocks#mock-using-module-factory-parameter) :

> In order to mock a constructor function, the module factory must return a constructor function. In other words, the module factory must be a function that returns a function - a higher-order function (HOF).

`mockDataCompiler` is defined above and is the main mock for the tests.

The mock module (ES6 class) is written as follow :

```js
jest.mock('@/path/to/MyClass', () => {
  return function (obj: object) {
    return { compile: mockDataCompiler, setParameters: () => null, ...obj };
  };
});
```

and instantiated in the main class like so:

```js
private myClass: MyClass = new MyClass(params);
```

This throws the following errors in the test :

- `TypeError: Cannot read property 'setParameters' of undefined` → so the mock is not instantiated
- `[Vue warn]: Error in data(): "TypeError: _MyClass.MyClass is not a constructor"` → there is no constructor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I solved it while writing the question.

The problem was that RelatedProductsCompiler was not a **default export**. The mock was also in the wrong scope. That's why any `constructor` was provided.

```js
jest.mock('@/utilities/planOverviewCompiler/RelatedProductsCompiler', () => {
  return { // Mock the whole module in this scope
    // Mock the RelatedProductsCompiler inside the module :
    RelatedProductsCompiler: function (params: PlanOverviewParameters) {
      return { compile: mockDataCompiler, setParameters: () => null, ...params };
    }
  };
});
```

Hope it will help others :)